# Server 2012 DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL

Tags: windows-server-2012

We have a Windows 2012 server that for a few months has been having random bluescreen events.

The server has all the latest Windows updates installed since this started happening, LAN & RAID drivers are the most recent from the manufacturer but is still happening.

I've used BlueScreenView to try and find the cause but no silver bullet yet sadly. Screenshots attached of the information from this.

[Bluescreenview image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXdhz.jpg)
[Bluescreenview image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JzgN.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated in solving this.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 0):

First suspect would be the network card being broken, since the crashes occur at network related drivers. Another suspect is the memory of the server being broken.